# How to implement "else if" on spark dataframe without UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

The below link explains how to implement IF ELSE in Spark.

[How do I use multiple conditions with pyspark.sql.funtions.when()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151861/how-do-i-use-multiple-conditions-with-pyspark-sql-funtions-when)

If my spark dataframe looks like this

```
A  B  C
10 2 300
20 3 200
30 7 500
20 1 700
```

But how do I implement the below logic which contains ELSE IF in spark.

```
If A>=20:
    flag = 1
elif B> 4
    flag = 2
elif C>500
    flag = 3
elif (1<A<20 & B<2)
    flag = 4
elif (1<A<20 & C<300)
    flag = 5
elif (100<C<400 & B>6)
    flag = 6
else flag = 0
```

Note:

- I want a solution directly on Spark dataframe without operation on RDD or UDF.
- I use chain of when otherwise for normal IF else condition but its difficult to implement ElSE IF with all conditions when there are lot of conditions.

Comment: The link that was shared as answer doesnt explain "else if" so its not a duplicate.