# How do I use multiple conditions with pyspark.sql.funtions.when() from a dict?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to generate a when clause based on values in a dict.  Its very similar to what's being done [How do I use multiple conditions with pyspark.sql.funtions.when()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151861/how-do-i-use-multiple-conditions-with-pyspark-sql-funtions-when/33157063)

Only I want to pass a dict of cols and values

Let's say I have a dict:

```
{
  'employed': 'Y',
  'athlete': 'N'
}
```

I want to use that dict to generate the equivalent of:

```
df.withColumn("call_person",when((col("employed") == "Y") & (col("athlete") == "N"), "Y")
```

So the end result is:

```
+---+-----------+--------+-------+
| id|call_person|employed|athlete|
+---+-----------+--------+-------+
|  1|     Y     |    Y   |   N   |
|  2|     N     |    Y   |   Y   |
|  3|     N     |    N   |   N   |
+---+-----------+--------+-------+
```

Note part of the reason I want to do it programmatically is I have different length dicts (number of conditions)

Answer (score 4):

Use reduce() function:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

# dictionary
d = {
  'employed': 'Y',
  'athlete': 'N'
}

# set up the conditions, multiple conditions merged with `&`
cond = reduce(lambda x,y: x&y, [ col(c) == v for c,v in d.items() if c in df.columns ])

# set up the new column
df.withColumn("call_person", when(cond, "Y").otherwise("N")).show()
+---+--------+-------+-----------+
| id|employed|athlete|call_person|
+---+--------+-------+-----------+
|  1|       Y|      N|          Y|
|  2|       Y|      Y|          N|
|  3|       N|      N|          N|
+---+--------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Yep, you right - with reduce it's really funny

Answer (score 1):

you can access dictionary items directly also:

```
dict ={
  'code': 'b',
  'amt': '4'
  }
list = [(1, 'code'),(1,'amt')]
df=spark.createDataFrame(list, ['id', 'dict_key'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

user_func =  udf (lambda x: dict.get(x), StringType())
newdf = df.withColumn('new_column',user_func(df.dict_key))

>>> newdf.show();
+---+--------+----------+
| id|dict_key|new_column|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|    code|         b|
|  1|     amt|         4|
+---+--------+----------+
```

or broadcasting a dictionary

```
broadcast_dict = sc.broadcast(dict)

def my_func(key):
    return broadcast_dict.value.get(key)

new_my_func = udf(my_func, StringType())

newdf = df.withColumn('new_column',new_my_func(df.dict_key))
>>> newdf.show();
+---+--------+----------+
| id|dict_key|new_column|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|    code|         b|
|  1|     amt|         4|
+---+--------+----------+
```

Comment: I went ahead and added some results, b/c this wasn't what I was tryin to accomplish.  Thanks for replying and my apologies for not being more clear in the original post