# Pyspark: Accessing a column within row in a UDF

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A beginner in pyspark trying to understand UDF:

I have a PySpark dataframe `p_b`, I am calling a UDF, by passing all rows of the dataframe. I want to access the column, `debit` from the row. For some reason, this is not happening. Please find the snippets below.

`p_b has 4 columns, id, credit, debit,sum`

### Function:

`def test(row):
    return('123'+row['debit'])`

### Converting to UDF

`test_udf=udf(test,IntegerType())`

### Calling UDF on dataframe `p_b`

`vals=test_udf(struct([p_b[x]  for x in p_b.columns]))
print(type(vals))
print(vals)`

### Output

`Column<b'test(named_struct(id, credit,debit,sum))'>`

Comment: It seems that you are trying to add '123' to every row to your dataframe. isn't?

Comment: you have to call your udf for your dataframe using with column, dataframe column value has to be passed as an argument.  Define your function like this.                               def user_func(row): 
    return row+123

Comment: my_func = udf(user_func, IntegerType()) 
newdf = df.withColumn('new_column',my_func(df.value))

Comment: see for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517381/how-do-i-use-multiple-conditions-with-pyspark-sql-funtions-when-from-a-dict/57518667#57518667

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was trying to add '123' to all rows of column 'debit'

Answer (score 1):

Let first make a sample dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *  
schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), True),\
                               StructField("credit", IntegerType(), True),\
                       StructField("debit", IntegerType(), True),\
                     StructField("sum", IntegerType(), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([("user_10",100, 10,110),("user_11",200, 20,220),("user_12",300, 30,330) ], schema)
df.show()
```

which results in:

```
+-------+------+-----+---+
|     id|credit|debit|sum|
+-------+------+-----+---+
|user_10|   100|   10|110|
|user_11|   200|   20|220|
|user_12|   300|   30|330|
+-------+------+-----+---+
```

Now, lets define the udf that adds 123 to the values passed to it:

```
def test(x):
    return(123+x)
test_udf=udf(test,IntegerType())
```

And lets see how to use the UDF:

```
df2 = df.withColumn( 'debit' , test_udf(col('debit')) )
df2.show()
```

which results in:

```
+-------+------+-----+---+
|     id|credit|debit|sum|
+-------+------+-----+---+
|user_10|   100|  133|110|
|user_11|   200|  143|220|
|user_12|   300|  153|330|
+-------+------+-----+---+
```

Note that now you probably need to recalculate the "sum" column:

```
df2 = df2.withColumn( 'sum' ,  col('debit')+col('credit') )
df2.show()
```

which results in:

```
+-------+------+-----+---+
|     id|credit|debit|sum|
+-------+------+-----+---+
|user_10|   100|  133|233|
|user_11|   200|  143|343|
|user_12|   300|  153|453|
+-------+------+-----+---+
```