# Pyspark Looking at first row and second row value and update the data sequentially

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark say suppose we have three column  `Start_date`, `duration`, `End_date`.
How can i look at the first rows `end_date` and second row `Start_date`. if second row `start_date` is greater than first row end date do nothing otherwise if first rows `End_date` is less than Second row `Start_date` then replace the second row `start_date` with first row `end_date` and add duration of second row to `start_date` and replace `end_date` of second row second row with new value. and do it for complete one group of ID.

Comment: it would help others answer your question if you could provide a reproducible example for your dataframe and required output.

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi - True but since i am new to Stack attaching Image is not allowed for me as of now. I tried attaching image now see if you can see it in my post.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data as they cant be copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ,  , it would help if you create a reproducible example  , Take a look at [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use window [**`lag/lead`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725353/applying-a-window-function-to-calculate-differences-in-pyspark) functions partitionBy `id`, orderBy `start_date` to compare first rows `end_Date` with second row `start_date`.

- Use [**`when otherwise`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151861/how-do-i-use-multiple-conditions-with-pyspark-sql-funtions-when) statement with [**`datediff`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020818/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-pyspark) function to caluculate difference of dates for `duration` column.

Comment: can i look at both rows at once. using lag function i know i can define a new column but here i want to update the end date sequentially.. so in one statement can do this operation .  can i write a function somethig like . when (lag 1 ,window) end_date < start_date ,  start_date = Lag1 ,window End_date , end date = start_date which is updated + duration , Else do nothing.